# jQuery Rollover

Tags: jquery, rollover

I'm simply hiding and showing a products descrption on rollover, can it be done better then this?

Its a little buggy when the mouse goes in and out

```
$("a.roll-over-trigger").hover(
   function() {
      $(this).next('.altProduct p').slideDown('300');
   },
   function() {
      $(this).next('.altProduct p').slideUp('300');
   }
);
```

a.roll-over-trigger is the image itself

and .altProduct p slides up over half of the image when hovered.

Here's a link http://tinyurl.com/d8dxd47

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an example that we can look at to see the "buggy" behavior you are referring to?

Comment: Check jQuery `.stop(boolean, boolean)` function in the docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide any example, just a guess

```
$("a.roll-over-trigger").on('hover', function(e) {
    $(this).next('.altProduct').find('p').slideToggle('medium');
});
```

[An example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/mXJrU/1/)